# ¿Por que no me toma el diseño del Jumbotron de Boostrap 5?

Tags: css, nodejs

Aplicacion con Nodejs.
adjunto fotografias.al momento de sacar la cdn de boostrap 5 del head, cambia la tipografia, por lo que me da a entender que esta tomando la insercción, ahora.. por que no me toma los estilos? quedo atento.
[image: Referencia del link de boostrap5 insertada]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hola Mundo</title>
    <!--Boostrap 5-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">   
     <!-- CSS personalizado -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" >
</head>

<body>

    <p>Navegacion</p>


<main class="container">
    
{{{ body }}}
</main>



    <p>Footer</p>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: Jumbostron con bg-light el cual sin bg no esta el predeterminado gris]

```
<div class="jumbotron m-3 bg-light ">
  <h1 class="display-4">Hello, world!</h1>
  <p class="lead">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
  <hr class="my-4">
  <p>It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within the larger container.</p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
</div>
```

[image: imagen del jumbotron. si saco el <link rel.. del boostrap 5 insertado en el main.hbs cambia la tipografia]

Comment: el codigo agregalo como texto..

Comment: El código fue agregado como texto.

Answer (score 1):

Solución: cambiar versión de Boostrap a la **v.4.6** funciona correctamente, se estaba haciendo uso de la **v5.0.0-beta1** .